# Mvvm and Mef and Item control template

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

I have the following case on my WPF app :

I have a main user control with its MainViewModel which binded to the control datacontext .

Inside the main control , I have an item control which item source is binded to List .

the item control has a user control as its template which draw the users details , each template as we know has User as its Datacontext .

My question :

How I can use the Main control datacontext (MainViewModel) in the template user control . I tried to use mef to import MainViewModel but the problem its exported with creation policy "NonShared" so the import will bring new instances of the MainViewModel and not the one of the Main control .

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Does your List/Collection look something like this? `ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces`

Comment: The main control is binded to MainViewModel , inside MainViewModel I have ObservableCollection<User> , the collection is binded to the item source of item control , and the data template inside the item control as you know hase now User on its data context

Comment: I handle this by importing the `ViewModel` and a `ResourceDictionary` that contains a reference to the `ViewModel` and `View`.

Comment: you can use RelativeSource in your bindings in your template to walk up the tree till you reach your mainview/mainviewdatacontext.

Comment: I think that you will need to add some more details for us to be able to help you. Maybe adding some example code of what you are trying to do, or something that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use MEF, you could always compose the existing value with a unique name, e.g.:

```
MainViewModel vm = DataContext;
container.ComposeExportedValue("SharedViewModel", vm);
```

That way, you can always provide an import for it in your user control:

```
[Import("SharedViewModel")]
public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

Where `ComposeExportedValue` is an extension method belonging to the `AttributedModelServices` type.